# Design pattern for Method parameter

Tags: design-patterns

I have a specific requirement like:

```
serviceUtility.invokeService(requestObj)
```

The above method takes the `requestObj`, which is not always the same object. It can contain any object depends on the functionality. But, the `invokeService` is the general method has to handle the request based on the object. I want to automate so that it dynamically identifies the object and act on the same. That means the implementation in the `serviceUtility` class would work for any type of object. Because the logic is same for every one. Now I am checking the object type and doing the logic.

Comment: So you want some sort of logic depending on the type of `requestObj`? Why? Why not put that logic in the `requestObj` class hierarchy?

Comment: You said the "implementation in the serviceUtility class would work for any type of object", but did you really mean *any*?  Can you pass a String, a Uri, a Button?  Is there a common set of properties or methods in the objects that you pass to invokeService that are required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the logic is same for every one

In this case you need to use [Generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). For example, in Java:

```
public <T extends Request> void invokeService(T object) {
  object.run();
}
```

Later, in the client:

```
utility.invokeService(new FooRequest());
utility.invokeService(new BarRequest());
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your programming language, you could do this dynamically by using reflection (e.g. in Java/C#); but it will be messy and hard to make it work perfectly.

You should reorganize your code, if possible and create an common interface, which all classes in question implement.  Then you *know* for sure they have the right methods and can call them without having to discover their exact type

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Creational Design Pattern named "Factory Method".

http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html